# When i try to rename files, i encountered an error about the File.Move method

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program to rename files, here's the code:

```
private void mainForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    number = e.KeyChar;

    void imageRename()
    {
        if(lstImages.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            selectedPicture = lstImages.Items[lstImages.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        }
        else{}

        #region
        if (number == '0')
        {
            words = radioButton1.Text.Split(' ');
        }
        else if (number == '1')
        {
            words = radioButton2.Text.Split(' ');
        }
        .
        .
        .
        #endregion
        renamedFile.Text = $"Renamed File: {words[3]}";
        newName = words[3];

        if( selectedPicture != null && newName != null)
        {
            //full file name: selectedPicture
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(selectedPicture);
            string name = Path.GetFileName(selectedPicture);
            string path = selectedPicture.Replace(name, "");
            newName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", newName, fileExtension);

            File.Move(selectedPicture, path + newName);
            
        }
        else
        {
            //show error
            showUnselectedImageError();
        }
    }
}
```

when i want to run my rename command i encountered this error:

> File.Move(selectedPicture, path + newName);
>
> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because it
> is being used by another process.'

Comment: My first check would be if the file you are trying to move is actually opened anywhere on the computer.

Comment: No the error message ("The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.") is quit clear.  But there is no indication the something is done with this error message.

Comment: 1) Install Process Explorer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer 2) Open it and press Ctrl+F. 3) Type in the name of the file you can't move and press Search. It takes time, but if the file is opened by another process, Process Explorer will show which one it is.

Comment: in my programme I am showing the picture at the same time in picturebox, therefore i may take this error.

Comment: what you can do then is 1. copy (not move) the picture to the new location. 2. reload the picture from its new location 3. delete it from the old location. also please try using the `try...catch` blocks to record all errors.

Comment: thank you for advice. i will try now